# Pages documents created on Yosemite cannot be opened by Pages on Yosemite after latest update (5.5.2)

Tags: macos, software-update, pages, error

Seemingly every single document that I created in the previous version of Pages (I update regularly whenever I see that a new update is available) on this same MacBook Pro with Yosemite will now not open with Pages after the latest update (5.5.2). I am still on Yosemite and nothing has changed aside from updating Pages, Numbers & Keynote.

All of my documents are stored on my internal hard drive. When I attempt to open them I get a message stating the following:

> This document can't be opened because it's too old. To open it, save it with Pages '09 first.

As I mentioned above, however, these documents were created in whichever version was right before the current version on the same computer with the same operating system (Yosemite).

Can anybody help? These are time sensitive documents. For now, I may try opening them with my iPad, but wow, if I knew this was going to happen I certainly would not have updated.